# WOT convergence of the operators

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ be sequences in $\mathfrak{B}(H)$ such that $A_n \to A$ in WOT and $B_k \to B$ in SOT. Show that $A_nB_n \to AB$ in WOT.

This is from Conway's book "A Course in Funcional Analysis". Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in H$.  We have to show that $\langle A_n B_n x, y \rangle \to \langle A B x, y \rangle$.  Try writing
$$\langle A_n B_n x, y\rangle - \langle ABx, y\rangle = (\langle A_n B_n x,y\rangle - \langle A_n Bx,y\rangle) + (\langle A_n Bx,y\rangle - \langle ABx,y \rangle).$$
For the first parenthesized term, observe that
$$|\langle A_n B_n x,y\rangle - \langle A_n Bx,y\rangle| \le \|A_n\| \|B_n x - Bx\| \|y\|.$$
Use the uniform boundedness principle to show $\sup_n \|A_n\| < \infty$ and conclude that this term goes to 0.  The second term is easier.